# Donner un coup de pied à quelqu'un

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

Je voudrais savoir s'il y a une façon plus courte de dire « Donner un coup de pied à quelqu'un » <=> « kick someone. »

Par exemple :

> Paul kicked Henry. <=> Paul a donné un coup de pied à Henri.

J'ai déjà entendu quelqu'un dire *chuté*. Je n'en suis pas sûr.

Comment: C'est bien "shooté" que tu as dû entendre, "chuter" signifie "tomber" et il est un peu tombé en désuétude.

Comment: Pas en désuétude, mais il a un sens littéraire. Le mot courant est tomber, et le mot littéraire est chuter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le terme dédié est "botter", mais à ma connaissance en Belgique et en France on ne l'emploie plus guère que dans l'expression "Botter les fesses" ou encore "Botter en touche". Son emploi dans d'autres conditions paraîtra certainement vieillot. De plus à ma connaissance on ne "botte" pas directement quelqu'un. Je n'ai jamais entendu "J'ai botté Gérard" mais bien "J'ai botté les fesses de Gérard".

On entends de plus régulièrement (en Belgique en tout cas) le terme "shooter", en référence au "to shoot" anglais utilisé notamment au foot, d'où la référence au coup de pied. Il est dans ce cas parfois prononcé "choter". On entend aussi parfois l'expression "se faire shooter" (avec la même prononciation). 
Néanmoins que ce soit dans l'un ou l'autre quand le destinataire du coup de pied n'est pas un objet le sens est souvent plus général et non limité aux coups de pied. Je le considère dans ce cas comme un synonyme de "tabasser/se faire tabasser".

Comment: Merci Laurent. J'ai bien compris.

Comment: Avec plaisir, mais je vous conseillerais d'attendre bien plus longtemps avant de valider une réponse, d'autant que la mienne est assez succinte donc d'autres ici pourraient en proposer de plus étoffées, mieux référencées, etc,...

Comment: D'accord, merci pour le conseil.

Comment: @LaurentS. Je crois pas avoir déjà entendu "shooter" prononcé "choté", toujours "chouté".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat > Je vais adapter ma réponse pour qu'elle soit plus nuancée, mais chez moi on "chote" dans le ballon. Ca fait un certain sens en plus : faire un  "shot" => "Shotter". Par contre lorsqu'il s'agit de drogue j'ai effectivement toujours entendu "se chouter". Désolé pour ces barbarismes mais je ne maitrise pas l'alphabet phonétique...

Answer (score 1):

Une facon plus familiere (argot) de dire ca est "Je lui ai mis un chassé".

Comment: Je ne connais pas cette expression. Aurais-tu une source ou une référence ?

Comment: Le chassé est un coup de pied donné avec la plante du pied en [savate (boxe francaise)](http://www.boxepiedspoings.fr/Coups-de-pied.html), c'est un terme technique encore utilisé (du moins il y a 15 ans quand j'en faisais ...). Par extension, je l'ai déjà entendu utilisé hors contexte pour désigner un coup de pied, mais je ne pense pas que tout le monde comprenne.